# Data synchronization between databases with different structures

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, opencart

I need an advice. I have 5 different cms on server and my task is synchronize user's data between them. 
Example: user register on website '1' and now he may signin on other 4 websites. User edit his account details.

My solutions:

1) On user signup triggers a synchronizing procedure (new row adds to each database/cms).

2) Is there other way to do this? ...

May I realize my 1 solution on sql (sql procedures, I mean trgigger script on adding new row)? or do I need deamon?

Comment: Aside from being too broad to answer, I really think a (more thorough) question along these lines would properly belong in the DBA forum.

Comment: I suggest looking into  MySQL Federated table engine

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Going to check it. Now I think that "sync daemon" is the best way, because amount of cms is various. And on adding new cms I have to modify each cms's db (too much work), it's better to add new db (table) to deamon's config.

Comment: What you're looking for is a Single Sign On (SSO) solution but as others have said this is a big project that can be approached in multiple ways.

Comment: Thank you @PaulFeakins, but I think we missunderstood each other. There is NO requirement that if user signin on website #1 he will signin on websiter #2,...
I just need synchronize user data tables (login, pass, adress, ...), so user don't need to register on other websites. Or may I don't understand what daoes SSO mean?

Comment: Ah right, well in that case why not write a script that runs regularly and looks at all databases and finds the customer record that was most recently updated, then copy the relevant fields across to the others?